# How to eliminate zeros when calculation corrolations in a dataset?

Tags: refactoring

I calculate  corrolation between  refactoring operations and I'm working on an android application so to do I calculate the number of refactoring type on each class the problem that I have many 'zeros' so for exemple I found the corrolation value between Extract Method ans inline method is 0,94639 witch is not logic when I verify the two column I found that the majority are zeros so he count them corrolated

I thought to do or operation between to cloumn, if I found two zeros I eliminate it but the problem I need also the corrolation between for exemple extract Method and Rename method

Is this any solutions for this problem ? 
Thanks in advance!